# Why is the solution of heat equation $f(x,t)= \int_{\mathcal{X}} f_0(x') \sum_{k \geq 1} e^{-t \lambda_k} \phi_k(x) \phi_k(x') \, dx'.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, convolution

In my notes, I have the solution of heat equation written as such
$$f(x,t) = e^{-t\,\Delta} f_0(x) \overset{(1)}{=}  \sum_{k \geq 1} \langle f_0, \phi_k \rangle_{L^2{\mathcal{(X)}}} e^{-t \lambda_k} \phi_k(x) \overset{(2)}{=} \int_{\mathcal{X}} f_0(x') \sum_{k \geq 1} e^{-t \lambda_k} \phi_k(x) \phi_k(x') \, dx'.$$

How are (1) and (2) attained? In particular I don't quite get how the inner product arises and why for the last expression, we have $x$ and $x'$?

Comment: $(1)$ is just the Fourier series expansion of $f$, where $f_{0}$ is your initial condition, $\phi_{k}$ your eigenfunction in $x$, $\langle f_{0}, \phi_{k} \rangle_{L^{2}( \chi )}$ is the inner product over the set $\chi$ that generates your coefficients, and $e^{-t \lambda_{k}}$ is your eigenfunction in $t$. $(2)$ is again the Fourier series expansion, but the inner product (coefficients) are written in integral form.

Comment: @Mattos Why then there is a $\phi_k$ at the end? From what I understand, $e^{-t \Delta} = \sum_{k \geq 0} \phi_k^T e^{-t \lambda_k} \phi_k$ and $f_0 = \sum_{k \geq 1} \langle f_0, \phi_k \rangle$, which do not match (1)? Can I know what am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: Maybe you are just getting confused by notation? Can you send me a link to the notes you are using? If by '$\phi_k$ at the end' you mean in the series at $(1)$, this comes from your original solution $f$. I can write a post if you would like detailing what I meant in my first comment if that helps?

Comment: @Mattos Sure thanks. My notes is https://www.dropbox.com/s/r4bzfux4ter8902/TUM%20Tutorial.pdf?dl=0 page 164 onwards

Answer (score 2):

Using your solution

$$f(x,t)=\sum_{k} a_{k} e^{- \lambda_{k} t} \phi_{k}$$

where $a_{k}$ are the coefficients, $\lambda_{k}$ the eigenvalues, $e^{-\lambda_{k} t}$ the eigenfunction for time, $\phi_{k}$ the eigenfunction in space, we find

\begin{align}
f(x,0) &= f_{0}(x) \\
&= \sum_{k} a_{k} \phi_{k}
\end{align}

Now, to use orthogonality conditions, we multiply both sides by $\phi_{k'}$ and integrate over the set $\chi$ i.e

\begin{align}
\int_{\chi} f_{0} \phi_{k'} dx &= \sum_{k} a_{k} \int_{\chi} \phi_{k} \phi_{k'} dx
\end{align}

Now, the LHS is just the inner product of $f_{0}$ and $\phi_{k'}$ in some space $\mathbb{T}$ over some domain $\chi$ i.e

$$\int_{\chi} f_{0} \phi_{k'} dx = \langle f_{0}, \phi_{k'} \rangle_{\mathbb{T}(\chi)} \quad (*)$$

and the RHS yields

$$\sum_{k} a_{k} \int_{\chi} \phi_{k} \phi_{k'} dx = \sum_{k} a_{k} \langle \phi_{k}, \phi_{k'} \rangle_{\mathbb{T}(\chi)}$$

which, by orthogonality, is just the inner product that gives the *normalisation*. On page $126$, it states that this normalising constant in the space $L^{2}(\chi)$ is given by $\langle \phi_{k}, \phi_{k'} \rangle_{L^{2}(\chi)} = \delta_{k k'}$ and so using this we find

\begin{align}
\langle f_{0}, \phi_{k'} \rangle_{L^{2}(\chi)} &= \sum a_{k} \langle \phi_{k}, \phi_{k'} \rangle_{L^{2}(\chi)} \\
&= a_{k} \delta_{k k'} \\
&= a_{k} \quad \text{when $k = k'$}
\end{align}

Replacing the coefficient in your Fourier series with the above yields

\begin{align}
f(x,t) &= \sum \langle f_{0}, \phi_{k} \rangle_{L^{2}(\chi)} e^{- \lambda_{k} t} \phi_{k}
\end{align}

which is the result you have at $(1)$. The result at $(2)$ is just the same as the result at $(1)$, but using the integral form at $(*)$ instead of the inner product. Also, the integral form is just integrating with respect to the dummy variable $x'$ instead of the dummy variable $x$.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: where do you get this $f(x,t)=\sum_{k} a_{k} e^{- \lambda_{k} t} \phi_{k}$ the very first equation?

Comment: That is the Fourier series solution to the heat equation on a finite domain with arbitrary boundary conditions. You can derive it yourself using separation of variables.

Comment: so $e^{-t\,\Delta} f_0(x) = \sum_k a_k e^{-\lambda_k t} \phi_k$?

Comment: I was thinking that it should be derived from $e^{-t\,\Delta} f_0(x)$?

Comment: $f(x,t) = e^{-t \Delta}f_{0}(x)$ is just a neat, shorthand way of writing the _solution_ to the problem using what is called the _heat operator_, which makes it easier to do analysis. It is reminiscent of the solution to an ODE of the form $f' = -f \implies f = f_{0}e^{-t}$ except in the ODE case $f_{0}$ is a constant. We know the solution on a bounded domain is given by $$f = \sum_{k} a_{k} e^{- \lambda_{k} t} \phi_{k}$$ through explicit calculation, implying $$f = e^{-t \Delta}f_{0}(x) = \sum_{k} a_{k} e^{- \lambda_{k} t} \phi_{k}$$

Comment: @Mattos Where can I find info on this shorthand way of writing the solution? I still cannot wrap my head around it.

Comment: @Mattos https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_kernel Seems like $a_k$ should be equal to $\phi_k$? Your derivation does still hold when $a_k$ is replaced with $\phi_k$. I am not sure how to derive the solution for heat equation but assume that the solution is $e^{-t\Delta}$ and by the definition of matrix exponential and $\Delta$, it seems to me that $a_k$ should be $\phi_k$

Comment: @user136266 $a_{k}$ is a _coefficient_, a number, a constant. $\phi_{k}$ is a _function_. And I'm not sure what I was supposed to read in the wikipedia page.

Comment: @Mattos Equation (1)